# How can a use jQuery to add a form label to the searchfield in jQuery mmenu v7.3.3?

Tags: label, mmenu

I need to add a form label to the search field input for accessibility. I'm using mmenu v7.3.3 on Shopify. How can I add the js needed to accomplish this?